# Defining OpenFOAM fields as functions of space

Tags: openfoam

I have some initial conditions that are specified by functions of (x,y,z).

I would like to programmatically define a field whose values are a function of (x,y,z). Can this be done as part of field construction, rather than looping over cells/faces and setting each value individually?

Further, can I set the internal field and boundary values in a straightforward manner?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `#codeStream` directive to enter the generating code directly in the field defining dictionary, see [official documentation](http://cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide/basic-file-format/#x18-1050004.2.11).

Also you might want to look at extensions such as [groovyBC](https://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Contrib/groovyBC), [funkySetFields](https://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Contrib_funkySetFields) or [swak4Foam](https://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Contrib/swak4Foam).

Comment: These look promising but, from what I've read of their documentation, only write vol fields, not surface fields.  Unfortunately I need to define both, without interpolation.